# Visual Studio Code - Flutter: Disable Autobreak

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, editor

I feel a bit stupid. I work with Flutter and switched to the Visual Studio code editor because it's a bit more comfortable to use.

Now I have a white vertical line there that moves all my lines every time I save something.

That's really annoying, especially since I work with Github, which creates huge commits because it breaks all lines.

Does anyone have any idea how I can change this?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you are using `Dart: Recommendation Settings`. If yes, then search `Dart: Recommendation` by pressing `Ctrl + Shift + P` and hit Enter. Once, the settings are applied you will get a `dialogue box` in `bottom right` of the screen having option of `open settings`. Click on it and you will get following settings. **Remove** the code in `red`

Try it. Cheers!

[image]

Comment: Also, instead of removing that code, you could set editor.formatOnSave = false, like Muhammad's settings.